# After merge videos, the duration is too long with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the same problem I think ... Do you have any ideas ?

This is the intro :

```
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Intro.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2021-01-27T07:13:48.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:06.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1386 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1053 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-01-27T07:13:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-01-27T07:13:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
```

And this is my video :

```
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:11:13.04, start: 10.000000, bitrate: 5246 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 5243 kb/s, 30.18 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

How can i convert my intro ?

Thank's

Comment: 1) ffmpeg has several ways to merge (concatenate). What command did you try to concatenate these videos? 2) Does `video.mp4` not have audio, or did you omit that info? 3) What is your OS?

Comment: 1) I used this command -> ffmpeg -f concat -i listFile.txt -c copy output.mp4 2) No audio 3) Ubuntu (and android after)

Answer (score 0):

All inputs to be concatenated [must have the same attributes](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/32597/how-to-create-compatible-avc-video-for-muxing-without-re-encode/32603#32603), same number of streams, and same type of streams. For your files:

0. Your `ffmpeg` is old. Before you do anything you should update `ffmpeg`. For Ubuntu you can [download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) a build that is already compiled, or follow a [tutorial to compile and install `ffmpeg`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).
1. Add silent/filler/dummy audio to `video.mp4` with the [anullsrc filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc):

   ```
   ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=stereo:r=48000 -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest video2.mp4
   ```
2. Re-export `Intro.mp4` from your editor to match the attributes of `video2.mp4`. Or, less ideal due to [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss), is to re-encode `Intro.mp4` with `ffmpeg`:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i Intro.mp4 -vf "scale=-2:720" -video_track_timescale 90k -c:a copy Intro2.mp4
   ```
3. Concatenate with the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) as you did previously.